GridDB Error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
I am setting up my first GridDB Java Application in NetBeans IDE. I am getting below error while running the application:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
at griddbconnection.Sample.<clinit>(Sample.java:6)

Header screenshot:

I have tried below sample code from the GridDB:
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Date;

import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Collection;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSException;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStore;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactory;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Query;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowKey;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowSet;

public class Sample {

    static class Person {
        @RowKey
        String name;
        int age;
    }

    static class HeartRate {
        @RowKey
        Date ts;
        int heartRate;
        String activity;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
        props.setProperty("notificationPort", "31999");
        props.setProperty("clusterName", "defaultCluster");
        props.setProperty("user", "admin");
        props.setProperty("password", "admin");

        try {
            GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);

            Collection<String, Person> people = store.putCollection("PEOPLE", Person.class);
            Query<Person> query = people.query("select * where name = 'John'");
            RowSet<Person> rs = query.fetch(true);

            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                // Update the searched Row
                Person person1 = rs.next();
                System.out.println("Name: " + person1.name + " Age: " + person1.age);
            }
            
            store.close();

        } catch (GSException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}

I have also added the latest jar file (gridstore-jdbc-5.5.0.jar) in my NetBeans project:

I have also added it in classpath environment variable :

Your any suggestions will be appreciated!

Put the following jar in classpath
gridstore.jar
You can find jar in /usr/share/java directory
